# Quiksoft.EasyMail.SMTP reference not found in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2015

We recently started using Visual Studio 2015 at work instead of 2013, and now we have found an issue that some of our projects are not building due to some references not being found, nothing has changed at all, just using vs2015 instead of vs2013.
One of the references is Quiksoft.EasyMail.SMTP, the error is the classic "The type or namespace name 'Quiksoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Me and a couple of coworkers have been trying to solve this, searching in the internet and we have not found why this is happening. We have the dlls (for example SMTP.Net.dll) and it is included in the References of the project.

We are out of ideas at this moment.

Have any of you had this issue in vs2015. I'm using this library as example but I wonder if there are more issues with vs2015 loading/finding references.

I hope is something silly and just need to turn on/off an option in vs2015.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your older project had a reference to the dll. Look in the bin folder of your old project or the lib folder if you have one, there will be a dll for it. Right click on references, "Add Reference" and navigate to the dll. Quicksoft is not a native assembly. You will most likely have to update the license on it as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stephen, however there is no old/new project or code, it is the same the only difference being that opening it with Visual Studio 2015 does not build, whereas VS2013 builds successfully.
I also tried re-adding the references a few times, that does not solve the issue.

Comment: It's a very old library and may not work in .NET 4.5 or above. Have you tried setting your target version back to 4 and tried building?